# DirectoryEntry giving com exception when trying to connect ldap server using secure port

Tags: c#, ssl, directoryentry

Exception snapshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB6qZ.png)
**STEP A**=>**Validating the proper certificate configuration**

I have a window service via which i am trying to connect the LDAP server from secure port 636 (SSL), all the certificate are properly 
configured and i have verified this using the tool ldap.exe and also check the portqry tool to check if the port 636 is listening or not
and **was successful in doing that**.

> **STEP B=>Code Snippet Which is not working for secure port 636(For SSL) but working correctly with non secure port (389) A strange
>   observation the Below  code works well when i run it as console based
>   application even with port 636 but fails when run as window service.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleLDAPWindowsService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            TestDirectoryEntryWay();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {


        }

        }
        public DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
        {
            // create and return new LDAP connection with desired settings  
            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = null;
            ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://abc.domain.com:636", "DomainAdmin", "DomainAdmin123", AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);
            return ldapConnection;
        }

        public void TestDirectoryEntryWay()
        {
            DirectorySearcher _searcher = null;
            SearchResult result_user = null;
            DirectoryEntry de = createDirectoryEntry();
            try
            {
                object o = de.SchemaEntry;//Getting a com exception  as the SchemaEntry is null not sure why as the same is working properly in port 389 
                _searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + "demouser1" + "))");
                if (_searcher != null)
                {
                    result_user = _searcher.FindOne();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Getting a com exception 

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**STEP C=>Code which is working in both port 636 and port 389 in window service**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleLDAPWindowsService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            // TestDirectoryEntryWay();
            var isLogged2 = SignInLDAP2("DomainAdmin", "DomainAdmin123", ""LDAP://abc.domain.com:636"", "abc.domain.com", true);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {


        }

        public  bool SignInLDAP2(string user, string psw, string ldapPath, string domain = null, bool useSSL = false)
        {
            // LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldapPath);

            var ldapDirectoryIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("abc.domain.com", 636, true, false);
            LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldapDirectoryIdentifier);

            if (useSSL)
            {
                ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;

                ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;

                ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
            }

            //var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("Hey", "There", "Guy");
            var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(user, psw, domain);
            try
            {
                ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);

                bool exists = UserExists("demouser1");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public bool UserExists(string username)
        {
            // create your domain context
            using (PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "abc.domain.com", "DomainAdmin", "DomainAdmin123"))
            {
                // find the user
                UserPrincipal foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, IdentityType.Name, username);

                return foundUser != null;
            }
        }



        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION Here is**

Is there a problem when working with Secure port with DirectoryEntry, as LdapConnection & networkCredential works smoothly with both the ports(636 &389),
 i have a legacy code which uses DirectoryEntry and i want it work for secure port as well can some one please help me, how to make the STEP B working for secure port 
 also.

Thanks in Advance for all the Support & guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the SSL certificate isn't trusted by the computer you're running this on.

I use Chrome to test this. Run Chrome like this (adjust for the path your Chrome is in):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --explicitly-allowed-ports=636
```

Then in Chrome, go to https://abc.domain.com:636. If the certificate is trusted, you'll see a "cannot connect" kind of message. But if it is not trusted, Chrome will give you a big red warning and you know that's the problem.

To trust the cert, you need to get the root certificate (as a file, likely *.cer or *.crt) and install it on every machine that will be running your code. Here are instructions for installing a root cert in Windows: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/manage-trusted-root-certificates-windows

Comment: Thanks Gabriel Luci for your reply , sorry i missed to reply back ...